# Customize Textbox in Access to time format

Tags: ms-access, vba

Is there a way (if needed, programatically) to precustomize a Textbox in Access so that a user can input "time" in a format like 18:00:00, but while the colons are already available and can not be "overwritten" by the user?
I mean this in the sense that a user would not need to type the colons; they would standard be available in the textbox.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the format to time and use an Input mask.

```
 Me.MyTime.Format = "Long Time"
 Me.MyTime.InputMask = "00:00:00;0;_"
```

Comment: This can also be set outside of VBA with the form in edit mode (and I know @KimGysen was asking for a programmatic means).

Comment: @Gaffi well this time it may be useful without, I have to do it for 20 textboxes for a weekly time registration form. Thanks for the tip!